# Private bitbucket repository in package.json with version

Tags: bitbucket, npm-install, node-modules, package.json

I am trying to include a private BitBucket repository to my package.json, but I also would like to manage the version, as a normal module.
currently I am using this

```
"package-name": "git+https://<user>:<password>@<url-repository>.git"
```

I already tried it, but it didn't work.

```
"package-name": "git+https://<user>:<password>@<url-repository>.git#v1.0"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Create a new branch like 1.0.0 and add the branch id end the end like git#1.0.0

Answer (score 36):

1. Login to your bitbucket account and under user settings add an app password:

   [image: > https://bitbucket.org/account/user/{yourUsername}/app-passwords]
2. Add package dependency to your `package.json` as:

> ```
> "dependencies": {
> "my-module": "git+https://Xaqron:pwd@bitbucket.org/Xaqron/my-module.git#*"
> }
> ```

Replace `Xaqron` with your own username and `pwd` with app password from step one.

to install specific version add `#v.v.v` (i.e. `#1.0.0`) to the end of dependency URL.

Comment: that version is the branch actually 
just to be clear

Comment: specifically to find out where to set app passwords see this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html

Comment: note:  you must use your master Bitbucket username, not the "label" of the app password you created in step one.

Comment: Will it always take that specific version that is in the tag, or does it work with operators such as `^`, `>` etc?

Comment: @AdamGerthel You can use version ranges by adding `#semver:whatever` at the end of URL. Example: `my-module.git#semver:^1.5.2`.

Comment: But this leaves my bitbucket password in package.json, which I'm likely to be tracking with git. Not a very secure solution.

Comment: @wolfson109: Yes and the project itself should be private but App password is different from main account password and you can revoke it at any time.

Comment: @wolfson109 use `git+ssh` instead.

Comment: @Xaqron i am using same steps, but this isn't working in my case. while installing it, showing premature close.

Comment: I followed the format but  I am getting the confusing message: git checkout 1.0.2, error: pathspec '1.0.2' did not match any file(s) known to git.  If I remove #1.0.2 at the end I get a premature close.

Comment: @nishant if the versions are following *semver* try using the syntax `#semver:^1.0.2`. Package.json is doing it's duty, that's a problem with Git not finding the branch a branch (or tag) `1.0.2`

Answer (score 23):

I am currently using this and it works:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "package-name": "git+ssh://git@<url-repository>.git#v0.1.0"
  }
}
```

I am using `npm` version `4.1.2` and self hosted bitbucket version `4.14.6`

Comment: The user needs to login using ssh authentication in bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

You have to git tag the version you want to install in the module repo. The repo url can be found in the module's `package.json` file, e.g.

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/repo-owner-name/my-module.git" // <-- This line!
},
```

When you've added a tag (e.g. `git tag -a 0.0.1 -m "auto release"`) to a release, it can be installed using:

```
"my-module": "git+https://bitbucket.org/repo-owner-name/my-module.git#0.0.1"
```